# How to successfully use {pkgdown} when `svglite` graphics device is used

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, pkgdown, svglite

To address [an issue](https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/issues/812) in my R package, I wish to try out an `svglite` graphics device for rendering `ggplot` plots:

```r
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = "svglite")
```

But, if I [do so](https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/pull/832/files), the {pkgdown} workflow fails ([failure log](https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/actions/runs/3917833998/jobs/6697870744)) with the warning messages:

```r
1: 'mode(bg)' differs between new and previous
     ==> NOT changing 'bg' 
2: 'mode(bg)' differs between new and previous
     ==> NOT changing 'bg'
```

If I understand correctly, these warning messages are coming from `par()`, which is complaining about not being able to change the background colour (`bg`). But I am not explicitly calling `par()`, nor am I changing the background colour for the plot in question.

So I wish to know why exactly am I getting this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example of your code, complete with the plot code.

Comment: I can't tell exactly where your problem stemmed from. I figured out you're using the branch 'try_svglite' and that you've modded the device in `setup.R`. I found that `ggstatsplot.RMD` calls `setup.R`. Does that mean that this error is stemming from `ggbetweenstats`? I have ran a standard RMD and I cannot duplicate the problem. Can you provide a little more (or a lot more) details regarding what is happening and what's triggering the problem? What were you testing specifically?

Comment: can you edit your pkgdown yaml to have an R script to set the option `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = "svglite")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a font mismatch issue.

Download necessary font files, make sure in the source package and register the necessary them with package 'systemfonts' and function `systemfonts::register_font()`. This is the right thing to do for packages 'svglite', 'ragg' (and 'ggiraph').

It looks like you have "greek" variant on your machine, but not on the GA remote machine.

In your package, I would add a new 'Suggests' entry with gdtools that can help you download the font and register it seamlessly (disclaimer, I am the author, but I really think it makes things easier). And in the vignette, before any graph production with 'ragg' or 'svglite', add the following code:

```
gdtools::register_gfont(family = "Open Sans", subset = c("latin", "latin-ext", "greek"))
```

Comment: @indrajeet-patil it worked? (I got points but not sure I should get them...)